# Linking Boost library on Cygwin

Tags: c++, boost, g++, cygwin

I have been at this for several hours now so I have come here to ask for help.
Pretty sure I almost have it figured out but I continue to have linker errors of undefined references to `boost::system::generic_category` and `boost::system::system_category`.

I have just one file I am trying to link to make an executable.

I began with compiling it to make an object file:

`g++ -c main.cpp -I C:/boost/boost_1_61_0`

This successfully creates main.o.

My next and final objective is to link it to an executable. I have tried different things from what I have read on other posts:

`g++ main.o -L C:/boost/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib`

`g++ main.o -L C:/boost/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.a`

`g++ main.o -lboost_system`

The result either tells me it can't find the library or something like:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x89): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::generic_category()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x95): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::generic_category()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa1): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::system_category()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost11this_thread9sleep_forERKNS_6chrono8durationIlNS_5ratioILl1ELl1000000000EEEEE[_ZN5boost11this_thread9sleep_forERKNS_6chrono8durationIlNS_5ratioILl1ELl1000000000EEEEE]+0x24): undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::hiden::sleep_for(timespec const&)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost11this_thread9sleep_forERKNS_6chrono8durationIlNS_5ratioILl1ELl1000000000EEEEE[_ZN5boost11this_thread9sleep_forERKNS_6chrono8durationIlNS_5ratioILl1ELl1000000000EEEEE]+0x24): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::this_thread::hiden::sleep_for(timespec const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know I built the boost libraries correctly as there is a libboost_system.a file along many other libraries in the stage/lib directory. Any ideas please?

Comment: Try doing both in one step: Tell it where the libraries are and link them at the same time: `g++ main.o -L C:/boost/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib -lboost_system`
Have you built boost with the same `g++` you're now using to link it?

Comment: that seems to have done it! Now there seems to be an undefined reference for boost::this_thread. Do you know what I link for that? And do I just add it as another link after -lboost_system?

Comment: Also, I am using the g++ that came from mingw. That should not make a difference right?

Comment: If you're using the same `g++` for both building boost and building your program, it's no problem.
To be able to use threads you need to link against `boost_thread`. Check this site to see the boost libraries that are not header only: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/more/getting_started/windows.html and thus need to be built and linked against (like `boost_system` and `boost_thread`).

Comment: what is the output of `g++ main.o -L /cygdrive/c/boost/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.a` ?

Comment: for your info Cygwin already has the library. https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libboost_system1.66/ .Of course you need also the devel package https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libboost-devel/libboost-devel-1.66.0-1 for making `g++ main.o -lboost_system` functional

Comment: "I am using the g++ that came from mingw". You are not using the Cygwin toolchain or Cygwin runtime environment then. You may be using the Cygwin shell but it doesn't matter much. So you are doing this "on Windows with mingw", not "on Cygwin".

Comment: @matzeri See my comment to the answer below regarding the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by looking at the commands you've tried.

```
g++ main.o -L C:/boost/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib
```

This tells `g++` to look for libraries in the `C:/boost/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib` directory. It doesn't say which libraries to pull in, but once you do, `g++` will look there.

Since your code has references to things (like `boost::system::generic_category`) found in `boost_system` and since you did not tell the linker to pull in that library, those references end up being undefined.

```
g++ main.o -L C:/boost/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.a
```

This tells `g++` to look for libraries in the `C:/boost/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.a` directory. Since this is (presumably) not a directory, there is no real effect of the `-L` flag.

```
g++ main.o -lboost_system
```

This tells `g++` to link in the `boost_system` library. While the linker knows how to convert a library name (e.g. `boost_system`) to the corresponding file name (e.g. `libboost_system.a`), there is no indication of where this file can be found. So the linker will look in the default directories it knows of. When the file is not found there, `g++` complains about being unable to find the library.

---

At this point you should see the two pieces that need to be combined: tell the linker which library to pull in and where to find it.

```
g++ main.o -lboost_system -L C:/boost/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried what you suggested and also added `lboost_thread` to get it to link properly, but I get this runtime error now: `error while loading shared libraries: cygboost_thread.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: This file it claims to not find (cygboost_thread.dll).. I can see it in my boost directory (C:/boost/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib) How can I help my program find it?

Comment: I assume you forgot the `make install` for your version of boost. `cygboost_thread.dll` should reside in the `PATH` so in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`. See as example the cygwin package content https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Flibboost_thread1.66%2Flibboost_thread1.66-1.66.0-1&grep=cygboost_thread